# How to calculate True positive rate in R?

Tags: r, q-value

I tried using qvalue function to calculate TPR:

```
library(qvalue)
qval_obj=qvalue(pvalR)
pi1=1-qval_obj$pi0
```

but after running:

```
qval_obj=qvalue(pvalR)
Error in smooth.spline(lambda, pi0, df = smooth.df) : 
  missing or infinite values in inputs are not allowed
```

or

```
 qval_obj=qvalue(pvalR,lambda=0.5)
Error in pi0est(p, ...) : 
  ERROR: The estimated pi0 <= 0. Check that you have valid p-values or use a different range of lambda.
```

I checked:

```
max(pvalR)
[1] 0.000352731
min(pvalR)
[1] 1.84872e-127
> sum(is.na(pvalR))
[1] 0
> sum(is.infinite(pvalR))
[1] 0
> length(pvalR)
[1] 129368
```

Also I tried using this flag: lambda=0 But:

```
> qval_objR=qvalue(pvalR,lambda=0)
> pi1=1-qval_objR$pi0
> pi1
[1] 0
```

Please advise,

Thanks
Ana

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Hi MrFlick I understand that but I am not sure how to reproduce it because it seems that the issue is with p values distribution...